# view IPs from apache access.log for date period

Tags: logs, apache-httpd, ip, date

I have seen someone use this command -- and it works where it pulls back all the IPS in a list/group:

```
cat access.* | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

However, I want to choose the past 2 days; how can I do that?

Comment: so before issuing the above coomand u need to filter the access log and get the entries for last two days , and pipe the output to the above command , to get the entries in a timespan see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/find-entries-in-log-file-within-timespan-eg-the-last-hour

Answer (score 1):

```sh
tail -100 access.* | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

or

```sh
awk '/28\/Mar\/2016/ { print $1 }' access.* | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```